# Replace variable name in string with variable value [R]

Tags: r, parsing, substitution

I have a character in R, say `"\\frac{A}{B}"`. And I have values for `A` and `B`, say `5` and `10`. Is there a way that I can replace the `A` and `B` with the `5` and `10`?

I tried the following.

```
words <- "\\frac{A}{B}"
numbers <- list(A=5, B=10)
output <- do.call("substitute", list(parse(text=words)[[1]], numbers))
```

But I get an error on the `\`. Is there a way that I can do this? I an trying to create equations with the actual variable values.

Comment: Your general approach is not going to work for you. If you try your code with `words <- "frac{A}{B}"` you get `Error in parse(text = words) : <text>:1:5: unexpected '{'
1: frac{`

Comment: @ShawnMehan -- Yeah, I tried that, too. It seems that there should be some general way to do this, like `sprintf` or something, but I can't figure it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the *stringi* function `stri_replace_all_fixed()`

```
stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed(
    words, names(numbers), numbers, vectorize_all = FALSE
)
# [1] "\\frac{5}{10}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sprintf(gsub('\\{\\w\\}','\\{%d}',words),5,10)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm more familiar with `gsub` than `substitute`. The following works:

```
words <- "\\frac{A}{B}"
numbers <- list(A=5, B=10)
arglist = mapply(list, as.list(names(numbers)), numbers, SIMPLIFY=F)
for (i in 1:length(arglist)){
    arglist[[i]]["x"] <- words
    words <- do.call("gsub", arglist[[i]])
}
```

But of course this is unsafe because you're iterating over the substitutions. If, say, the first variable has value "B" and the second variable has name "B", you'll have problems. There's probably a cleaner way.